# Finding Decimal In .Element C# XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with my C# API not finding element decimals (returning error)
Here's the XML file

```
 <CHandlingDataMgr>
    <HandlingData>
        <Item type="CHandlingData">
            <handlingName>Plane</handlingName>
            <fMass value="140000.000000" />
            <SubHandlingData>
                <Item type="CFlyingHandlingData">
                    <handlingType>HANDLING_TYPE_FLYING</handlingType>
                    <fThrust value="0.630000" />
        </Item>
        </Item>
</SubHandlingData>
</HandlingData>
```

I'm aiming to show the handlingName & fMass value into my RichTextBox

Here's the C# code :

```
string path = "Data//handling4.meta";
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var items = doc.Descendants("HandlingData").Elements("Item");
var query = from i in items
            select new
            {
                HandlingName = (string)i.Element("handlingName"),
                HandlingType = (string)i.Element("SubHandlingData")
                                        .Element("Item")
                                        .Element("handlingType")//.Attribute("value").Value
            };
StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in query)
{
    string k = item.HandlingName + item.HandlingType ; 
    test.Append(k);
    richTextBox1.Text = test.ToString(); 
}
```

The above code works perfectly, providing the handling name & handling type, my problem however, is the thrust values because the thrust value is decimal, however subhandlingdata is a string(tag), so my question is how to find a decimal inside of a string's element?

I have tried placing `(decimal?)` inside many different sections of `.Element("fThrust").Value` with no luck. If using `(decimal?)i.Element("fThrust").Attribute("value")` it returns 'not set to object' because this method doesn't look inside sub-item (subHandlingData)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your XML is invalid (you're closing SubHandlingData before closing Item) and your code is painful to read because you haven't formatted it properly. Please fix these. It's hard to help you without seeing the *valid* XML. Tour `i.Element("fThrust")` attempt would fail as `fThrust` is withint he *inner* item, not the outer one.

Comment: Your XML is *still* invalid.

Comment: Please view the doc for yourself, I have uploaded to Google Drive & shortened the link: http://bit.ly/XeazCL , I believe my XML looks ok? This item is located near the bottom, also I have all other elements in a separate program (only thrust inside subhandlingdata is my problem)

Comment: I dare say the real XML is okay, but the version in the question is not. You've got `<Item><SubHandlingData><Item></Item></Item></SubHandlingData>`. I'll try the real doc, but you should really fix up the question too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be selecting the `fThrust` element within the *inner* item, not the outer one - just as you're already doing for `HandlingType`:

```
Thrust = (decimal?) i.Element("SubHandlingData")
                     .Element("Item")
                     .Elements("fThrust") // There may not be an element
                     .Attributes("value")
                     .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. =(

Comment: @DannyNichols: Well if you would provide some *valid* sample XML, I could test it... but that really should be fine. Does every top-level item have a `SubHandlingData` element with an `Item` element in it and an `fThrust` element within that?

Comment: @Thirisangu: Why did you put a `.Value` in there? My code doesn't have that, does it? I wouldn't expect the code to even *compile* like that. And that doesn't answer my question, either.

Comment: @JonSkeet To get the value of Attribute we do so.

Comment: @Thirisangu XAttribute has an explicit cast overload for Nullable<Decimal>... you can't use the Value property like that. You'd have to parse it to a decimal rather than cast.

Comment: @Thirisangu: Please don't guess at changes required to my code - instead, try my *actual* code. Look at the documentation for `XAttribute` for all the explicit conversions available. You only want to use `Value` when you want the value *as a string*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Excellent.,Accept it.,+1 for brilliant answer

Comment: Sorry for late reply, was hoping this would be straight forward. @JonSkeet , every SubHandlingData element does contain an item, but each does not contain thrust. You can view the full doc here: http://bit.ly/XeazCL Furthur note: I have all other elements mapped, my problem is only with subhandling data section & thrust viewing. Thrust is found under HandlingName jet

Comment: @DannyNichols: Okay, try my revised answer. Basically it will try to find *all* `fThrust` elements under the `Item`, which may mean 0 of them... basically you'll end up with either an attribute or null by the end, and you can convert to `decimal?`. Do you understand why that information about the document would have been really nice to have when you originally asked the question two and a half hours ago?

Comment: If either of the Elements requested are null, will the use of FirstOrDefault() cause a null value to be returned or will a NullReferenceException occur?

Comment: Works great, thanks! & I was honestly not sure if links were aloud, sorry for not posting it originally =D @JonSkeet

Comment: @DannyNichols: We didn't actually need a link - just a *real* bit of XML with the data in, and an explanation that the `fThrust` element might be missing.

Comment: @JamieKeeling: It would fail if the `SubHandlingData` or `Item` elements were missing, but it handles `fThrust` being missing. That's in line with what the OP has told us about the expected nature of the doc.

Comment: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/08/22/stack-overflow-and-personal-emails/ <-- Love it, Laughed so bad. @JonSkeet , I hope to bump into you again on more experienced grounds. Legend